# Derived table used several times

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, derived-table

I need to run 3 consecutive queries using the same derived table... I'm using MS SQL Server 2008

```
Select a,b,c from categories inner join (select x,y,z from derivedTable where…) …
Select a,b,c from users inner join (select x,y,z from derivedTable where…) …
Select a,b,c from orders inner join (select x,y,z from derivedTable where…) …
```

Is there a way to run the 3 sql queries at the same time in a way the derived table

```
(select x,y,z from derivedTable where ...)
```

is executed only once?

I’m using .net so... I’m wondering if I could return the 3 tables and load a dataset with the 3 tables.

Thanks

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `WITH`:

**Note:** As pointed by @Martin `WITH` is evaluated several times so the correct solution is the temporary table.

```
WITH derivedTable (x,y,z)
as
(
    select x,y,z
      from derivedTable
      ...
)
SELECT a, b, c
  FROM users
  join derivedTable on ...
 WHERE ...
union all
SELECT a, b, c
  FROM orders
  join derivedtable on ...
 WHERE ... 
union all
 ...
```

or a temporary table:

```
select x,y,z
  into #derivedTable
  from derivedTable
  ...

SELECT a, b, c
  FROM users
  join #derivedTable on ...
 WHERE ...
union all
SELECT a, b, c
  FROM orders
  join #derivedtable on ...
 WHERE ... 
union all
 ...
```

Comment: +1 Though temporary not temporal. Just to make clear the CTE will be evaluated multiple times the `#temp` solution won't.

Comment: Thank you David and Martin. So, Martin what are you saying is that using "WITH derivedTable" the querie will be executed several times?

Comment: Thank you @Martin for the corrections. In Spanish is "temporal" :) @user996760 Yes, `with` could be evaluated several times.

Comment: @user996760 - Yes. The execution plan will show that the CTE is not materialised up front into a temporary table and the base tables are accessed multiple times. You can also see this from `;WITH CTE(id) AS (SELECT NEWID()) SELECT * FROM CTE c1 JOIN CTE c2 ON c1.id = c2.id` (Returns zero results)

Comment: @user996760: That's right, the `derivedTable` CTE will be evaluated as many times as it is referenced in the query. One other advantage of the `#temp` solution over the CTE one (though maybe not necessarily useful in your particular case) is that you can use the temporary table in *separate* queries (within the same scope, of course), while the CTE is only accessible within the statement where it is defined.

Comment: More details on how non-recursive CTEs work: [1](http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2008/05/17/non-recursive-common-table-expressions-performance-sucks-1-cte-self-join-cte-sub-query-inline-expansion.aspx) & [2](Non Recursive Common Table Expressions).